# Select objects from get_posts()

Tags: get-posts

How can I select the first/last object from the list returned by get_posts()?

How can I select the preceding/following object relative to an arbitrary object in the object list returned by get_posts?

How can I extract a sublist from the list returned by get_posts()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like more of PHP question than a WordPress one - `get_posts()` just returns an array of objects; interact with them like you would any other numerical array:

```
$posts = get_posts();

$first_post = $posts[0];
$last_post = array_slice( $posts, -1, 1 );

$everything_but_first_last = array_slice( $posts, 1, -1 );
```

Check out the [complete list of array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: Thanks for the list. For some reason I can only reference by index the first eight objects, even though `print_r($objects);` prints them all out (all 123 objects), as does a `foreach` loop. I get `Undefined offset: 8` for index 8 and other higher that I've tried. Any ideas why?

Comment: My code was bad. I can now reference any index.

Comment: The list of PHP array functions was very useful. I found answers to my questions using that and some examples I found on the web. In particular, I used array_keys combined with array_search to get the preceding/following object inspired by this Stack Overflow post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3782274/1257965)